# "Header already sent" error in Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl, warnings

I'm working on a *Wordpress* site and I have set an *SSL certificate*. I got the following error,

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at /var/www/mylink/wp-config.php:1) in
>   /var/www/mylink/data/www/mylink/wp-login.php on line 411
>        Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/mylink/data/www/mylink/wp-config.php:1)
>   in /var/www/mylink/data/www/mylink/wp-login.php on line 424.

[image]

I have tried blank spaces, echo before php tag, and many more but was not able to solve this issue. I'm not able to open my admin panel and when I open my site with `wp-admin` URL, it shows only the above error. If I open my admin panel with `wp-login.php`, it shows login page but I'm not able to logged in.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.
Please check the image for further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try below solution?
ob_start();
ob_get_clean();
It will do get current buffer contents and delete current output buffer.